# Code Coverage for .NET Core 2.0 projects in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, code-coverage

**Version: 15.4.1 - Visual Studio Enterprise 2017**

I created a simple .NET Core 2.0 library project and added a UnitTest Project to it. When I run Test -> Analyze Code Coverage -> All tests. Code Coverage Results only report the code coverage for the unit test project.

[image]

I already configured the project according to [Working with Code Coverage](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/analyze.md#working-with-code-coverage). This is my .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

    <!-- Required in both test/product projects. This is a temporary workaround for https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/800 -->
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.2.0" />

    <!-- Required. Include this reference for coverage -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeCoverage" Version="1.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Update:**
I added the same code in the solution as .NET 4.6.2 projects and ran Code Coverage again. It covers the class library just as you would expect:

[image: Code coverage covers the code of the class library]

So my Visual Studio is correctly configured to run Code Coverage. At least for .NET 4.6.2. I also tried it in a fresh VS installation and in VSTS.

I created a [repo with my sample code](https://github.com/saciervo/NetCoreCoverage). Can anyone else reproduce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround that I didn't fully understand.

You have to add `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>` to **all the projects** that you need to cover. Not the unit test itself.

Comment: Where exactly do you add full in .Net core cproj file?

Comment: @Idothisallday `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'"><DebugType>full</DebugType><DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols></PropertyGroup>`

You can also do this through the GUI, right-click the project, properties, build, advanced... (button at the bottom right).